Bedouin and tattoos
Tattoos are haram, but historically they are quite common among the Bedouin tribes.
Are the Bedouin shunned by other Muslims, or is the conflict handled in some other way?

According to Shia fiqh Tattoos are not forbidden as long as the colorful material is used under the skin or will leave no noticeable mass over the skin to prevent water in Wozu or Qusl to reach the skin.
Ref in Persian
